# YouTube Analytics API channel: The response has no rows parameter

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics

When using the API for retrieving aggregated metrics for the `channel`'s content the report returns a single row of data that contains totals for each requested metric during the specified date 
range.

Here's an [API Example link](http://goo.gl/5z2W0u).

Sometimes not even account information is received; the object `rows` is not present in the response but only `columnHeaders`, even though the account has the appropriate fields populated (I can see it on the profile available on youtube).

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Why sometimes I do not receive field rows with the information?

Comment: You need a `Bearer token` to try, i can send you one token that does not work

Answer (score 0):

I have made the same observations as jay. Somehow some metrics returned no result rows. But for me it turned out that those missing rows were also not available in youtube's Analytics integration.
[image]

As you can see, all "Interaktionen (Interactions)" have 0 values, but the "Geteilte Inhalte (shares)" column differs from the rest. It has no values attached. If you click on the metric you get the following notification

[image]

It says: "There is no data available at the moment, chose a diffrent time range or wait some more days".

So for me the API data was always corresponding with youtube's analytics integration.